# How to change all patches to a same random pcolor?

Tags: netlogo

actually i have a very simple problem but i find no solution to it.
I want to change the color of all patches to a same random color.

Could you help me please?

Greets,
Yannick

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
let n random 140
ask patches [set pcolor n]
```

Previously commented by @Alan

Answer (score 1):

You will need to specify what you mean by a "random color", but the following may get you started.

```
to test
  let r random 256
  let g random 256
  let b random 256
  let c (list r g b)
  ask patches [set pcolor c]
end
```

Comment: This answer has more educational value! Demonstrates the rgb formula.